# Summing the values in list view, cannot access column

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to sum the values in column 3 (Jobs) and 4 (Bids) in my listview PlotListView for a WPF application I am working on. This is what I've done so far:

```
int jobSum = 0;
int bidSum = 0;
foreach (ListViewItem item in PlotListView.Items)
{
    jobSum += int.Parse(item);
    bidSum += int.Parse(item);
}
```

Code for listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="PlotListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="228" Margin="5,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="424">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                        <GridViewColumn Width="99" Header="Plot" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PlotId}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="99" Header="Area" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Area}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="99" Header="Jobs" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Jobs}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="99" Header="Bids" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bids}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to access the exact column - am I on the right track? What do I need to do?

Comment: Can you check and index or name of the ListViewItem?

Comment: @impr0t - I've included the code for the listview in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know the exact type of your items, so I used `dynamic`. It will be better, if you replace `dynamic` with the actual type of the items.

```
int jobsSum = 0;
int bidSum = 0;
foreach (dynamic item in PlotListView.ItemsSource)
{
    jobsSum += int.Parse(item.Jobs);
    bidSum += int.Parse(item.Bids);
}
```

In short, `ItemsSource` contains the data and `Items` property holds the generated visuals for the data.

Comment: Thanks but your approach doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I tried the following http://pastebin.com/aqidwXhV based on your code as well but it doesn't work either. Any idea why?

Comment: @methuselah I've written the actual code using the XAML you've provided. Just copy it and paste.